# Discord.js guildCreate/guildDelete events don't seem to be working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot send an embed to a channel aswell console logging it but once the bot leaves or join it doesn't work at all no errors in the console nothing is the problem with the code? I checked the channel ID it's correct and nothing wrong with it

```js
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => { 
    const EmbedJoin = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setDescription(`Guild owner: ${guild.owner.user.tag}\nMembers: ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Joined New Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(`758356170926325790`).send(EmbedJoin)
});

//Left Guild
client.on("guildDelete", (guild) => {
    const EmbedLeave = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setTitle(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}.`)
    .setDescription(`Guild owner: ${guild.owner.user.tag}\nMembers: ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(`758356170926325790`).send(EmbedLeave)
});
```

Comment: Heyo, I asked this yesterday. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934077/send-a-message-to-my-private-channel-on-join-leave

Comment: Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch() the channel with the method [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) and it fetches the channel by using its ID if it's available in the cache. Try the following code please:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", async(guild) => {
    const fetchedChannel = await client.channels.fetch(`758356170926325790`);
    const EmbedJoin = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setDescription(`Guild owner: ${guild.owner.user.tag}\nMembers: ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Joined New Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    fetchedChannel.send(EmbedJoin)
});

//Left Guild
client.on("guildDelete", async(guild) => {
const fetchedChannel = await client.channels.fetch(`758356170926325790`);
    const EmbedLeave = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setTitle(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}.`)
    .setDescription(`Guild owner: ${guild.owner.user.tag}\nMembers: ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    fetchedChannel.send(EmbedLeave)
});
```